# Edit the selected option text in "ng-options" select-list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I need to add the text `"(Default)"` to the selected-option text. please help me...

> The text should be "Visa 1881 (Default)".

But its only showing `"Visa 1881"`. Here is my code:

```
<select ng-options="item.brand + ' ' + item.last_digits for item in approvedinvoicesCtrl.current_job.cards" ng-model="approvedinvoicesCtrl.GetCard"></select>

var vmc = this;

vms.current_job = response.data.payment_info;

for (var i = 0; i < vmc.current_job.cards.length; i++){
    if (vmc.current_job.cards[i].is_default){
        vmc.GetCard = vmc.current_job.cards[i] + ' (Default)';
    }
}
```

What I get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv3Rb.jpg),

And what I need is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYglC.jpg).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to initialize using `ng-init` default value:

```
<select ng-init=" approvedinvoicesCtrl.GetCard = initialValue" 
        ng-model="approvedinvoicesCtrl.GetCard" 
        ng-options="item.brand + ' ' + item.last_digits for item in approvedinvoicesCtrl.current_job.cards">
</select>
```

**Updated:**

jsfiddle link:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/g2j6863a/6/
```

working as you want.

Hope this will work.

Comment: mujhe Default word lagana hai... apne card value k agge

Comment: Sorry check this: https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/g2j6863a/6/ url changed for jsfiddle after updation, check now

Answer (score 0):

In your `if()` statement, you're **assigning** a value to `cards[i].is_default` instead of **evaluating** it. So not only your condition will always be `true` ,  `cards[i].is_default` value will also be `(String) "true"`.

```
if (this.current_job.cards[i].is_default = 'true') 

// Should be 

if (this.current_job.cards[i].is_default == 'true')
```

You should use `==` instead of `=`.

---

Do you want the `option` text to be `Visa 1881 (Default)` instead of `Visa 1881`?

In this case you can just add a string to the value:

```
 this.GetCard = this.current_job.cards[i] + ' (Default)';
```

Comment: Did you change `=` to `==` ? If so, please edit and fix the code block in your question. If the `ng-model` will get a correct value you should be good and the option will be selected.

Comment: Try using this : `if (this.current_job.cards[i].is_default)`. Perhaps the value of `is_default` is not a string, but a Boolean